# Efficiently counting independent events in a given time range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

#### Problem description

I came across this problem a couple of times and always wondered if my solution was optimal or (far more probable) there is a better one.

Say that my component receives events, that are composed of a time and a string. For every event I receive I need to return how many independent strings were seen in the last `x` seconds. (`x` is configurable but fixed at the beginning of the execution). By "last `x` seconds" I mean the time range that ends at the time of the event with the highest timestamp and lasts `x` seconds (both ends included).

Let me give an example. I receive the following events (represented by the `(time, string)` pair) in the given order, and for every event I show the expected return value, assuming `x = 5`.

- (1, "a") → 1
- (2, "b") → 2
- (3, "a") → 2
- (7, "c") → 3
- (9, "c") → 1
- (8, "d") → 2

We cannot assume the events to come in the right order, but we can assume the discrepancies to be small, i.e., that if you put the events in an ordered list, you are in most cases adding the event at the end of the list or very close to it.

Also, the string is a simplification here. They are actually objects that one can compare for equality and compute an hash of, but not order nor do fancy things with. (I will nevertheless call these objects "strings" in the rest of the question.)

---

#### My solution

I would use two data structures: a double-ended queue and a hash map. The former contains the events in order of time, the latter contains the strings seen in the last `x` seconds along with a counter of how many time they have been seen.

For every event received I would add it to the queue and increase the counter in the map. Then I would move to the beginning of the queue and remove from it all those event whose timestamp is too old (i.e. lower than `time_of_last_event - x`); for each removed event I would decrement the corresponding counter in the map, and remove the entry from the map if its counter is zero. At the end the size of the map is the number I have to return.

If out-of-order events occur often, but events are "almost-in-order", I could consider to use a double-linked list rather than a double-ended-queue; when inserting events I would search backwards from its end to find the suitable place for the event to insert. This would save me from too many reallocations, but I'm not sure allocating memory for each event I insert would pay off in terms of performance.

Assuming constant time insertion at the end of the queue, constant-time removal from its beginning and constant-time operations in the hash map, I would say that each call to this algorithm would be amortized constant-time (in the long run, I will remove as many entries as I insert, so in average one per call).

---

The main question is: **Is there a better algorithm than the one described?**
By better I mean and algorithm that would run faster or use less memory.

A few more questions

- Is anything wrong with this algorithm?
- Is this a well-known problem? Is there a name for it? I could not find anything, but I might have searched the wrong keywords.

Comment: Why the example has (8, "d") → 2? I would have thought 3 ("a", "c" and "d")?

Comment: When you insert (8, "d"), the latest event you have in the list is (9, "c"). The time frame is computed so that it ends at the time of the latest event in the list, so it is [4, 9]. In this range, the events are `(7, "c")`, `(8, "d")` and `(9, "c")`.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed. Missed that the latest event had time stamp 9

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is efficient enough if you receive the events in order, but if not, the algorithm becomes quadratic, as the effort to insert a new element in the doubly linked list in a sorted position will need linear time (in terms of the size of the list). This may not be an issue if you regard *x* a constant, because then the total time complexity is still *O(n)*. If however, you think of *x* as a variable, then this is not optimal.

The solution is to use a Min Heap instead of a queue or doubly linked list:

Insert each new element in the heap, keyed by the time stamp. When the heap gets a size that is one greater than *x*, then remove the root of the heap, as it represents the oldest entry compared to the *x* other entries in the heap.

For the rest you can continue with the hash map as you were doing.

As an insertion and a removal from the Heap has *O(logx)* time complexity, the total time complexity is *O(nlogx)*.